# Logoff form giving null exception in login control c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, security, login-control

I am using websecurity login with mv3.
I am stuck with this problem
The error faced  by me is :-
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
Line 53:                                 <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" class="logout"></a>
Line 54:                             }
Line 55:                         </li>
Line 56:                     </ul>
```

Source File: d:\Warid\HrmsWaridNew\HrmsWaridNew\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml    Line: 54

the login controller code..

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (checkLogin(model.UserName))
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                Session["UserID"] = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId.ToString();
                Session["UserName"] = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName.ToString();

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }

[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            WebSecurity.Logout();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = null;

            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
```

Comment: Please don't put "regards" sentence in your question as your name is already visible to everyone. It is considered a bad practice on SO.

Comment: Thee is no need to post full StackTrace and make the question creepy.

Comment: i disagree I find creepy questions are easier to read, especially around halloween

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i infer from the details you have provided. That there is a file in your project named as **Shared_Layout.cshtml**. In this file you have got an object on line 36,37,38 or 39 which you are trying to use without instantiating it first.

Now, how will you know what is null. It is very simple as well. Click on the **line 36** and press <kbd>F9</kbd>. It will place a **break point** in your application. Now press <kbd>F5</kbd> it will start the debug process. Now logoff and your debugger will stop at the line you placed the debugger. Now you can see what is null.

Comment: i already do that thing.. every thing is correct ... but after closing bracket. it give this error... and also if i comment the logoff form.. it give the same error at @RenderSection("javascript", required: false) in my _layout page..

Answer (score 0):

The line in your question says:-

**Object Reference not set to an instance**  
 **NullReferenceException**

Null reference exception occurs when we fail to initialize a reference type in our code, and try to use it afterwards.
foreg

```
   List<string> myList = null ; 
   myList.Add("Tom") ; // This will throw a null reference exception.
```

To correct it  Properly initalize a reference type in C#

```
  List<string> myList = new List<string> () ; 
  myList.Add("Tom") // compiles and runs fine.
```